# Audio file doesn't play in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio-player

I've been trying to play an audio file in Recact.js but it doesn't play.
I'm not facing any error the scroll bar shows up but play button doesn't work. I've tried playing the song to check if the file is corrupted. the mp3 file works fine.

```
import React from 'react'

class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <audio ref="audio_tag" src="./abc.mp3" controls autoPlay/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Comment: is your audio file copied to the root folder of your app?

Comment: Make sure that you have correct audio file and the URL is correct too. To be sure, inspect your audio and open its source in a new tab.

Comment: My audio file is in the same folder as the .js file, yes

Comment: I tried playing the mp3 file and it does, how else can I check?

Comment: importing the file and using it directly is probably the way to go... see the alternative method in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134317/audio-file-doesnt-play-in-reactjs/58134575#58134575

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using create-react-app I suggest that you move your mp3 file to the public folder and then try the following with what I called pathToPublic whatever path you need to go down to your file:

```
import abc from '.../pathToPublic/public/abc.mp3'

<audio
  ref="audio_tag"
  autoPlay={true}
  controls={true} >
  <source type="audio/mp3" src={abc} />
</audio>
```

And let us know if it works.

Comment: ok. Is your mp3 file located in the same folder as your component? The path that is used for `src` could be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest, dod you build your app from scratch or did you try with `create-react-app`?

Comment: It is in the same folder. I used create-react-app

Comment: I faced a similar issue with create-react-app in the past and I solved by moving my medias in the public folder where files are  not processed by Webpack. Ive updated my code so you can give it a try.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it did :)

Answer (score 2):

`./` is a relative path, so your audio file will need to be served from the same folder as your bundle.

If you want to keep your audio files and the player decoupled, this is fine, but to make it work sure that a) your file is copied to your app's output folder somewhere and b) you reference the path from the root, so something like:

```
class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <audio ref="audio_tag" src="/assets/sounds/abc.mp3" controls autoPlay/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can alternatively import your audio file and use it directly:

```
import abc from './../path/to/file/abc.mp3';

class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <audio ref="audio_tag" src={abc} controls autoPlay/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a working sandbox that demonstrates the importing method: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-leakey-7lk6f

Comment: My audio file is in the same folder as this .js file, should I make any amends?

Comment: yes, because when it gets bundled they won't be 'together' any more

Comment: have added an alternative method that might suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Can you place right src file? or just put external if you want to check

```
  <div>
    <audio ref="audio_tag" src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" controls autoPlay/>
  </div>
```

Or

```
<audio
  ref="audio_tag"
  autoPlay={true}
  controls={true}>
  <source type="audio/mp3" src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Comment: This did work!!! But I don't understand why my song won't. Please explain.